# How to add and compute (based on other columns) a sub-column in a pandas dataframe with hierarchical index?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am new to pandas and I am trying to grasp the multiindex mathematics...

Let's say we have a pandas dataframe with 2D columns and 2D rows, as in the example, how can we add a "sub-column" `('ALPHA', 'gamma')` which values are equal to
`(same d1, same d2, 'ALPHA', 'alpha') +
(same d1, d2-1, 'BETA', 'alpha')` , that is `('A',2,'ALPHA','gamma')` is 10+2 ?

```
ridx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A',1),('A',2),('A',3),('B',1),('B',2),('B',3),('C',1),('C',2),('C',3)], names=['d1', 'd2'])
cidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('ALPHA','alpha'),('ALPHA','beta'),('BETA','alpha'),('BETA','beta')], names=['d3', 'd4'])
dfmix = pd.DataFrame([(0,1,2,3),(10,11,12,13),(20,21,22,23),
                      (30,31,32,33),(40,41,42,43),(50,51,52,53),
                      (60,61,62,63),(70,71,72,73),(80,81,82,83),                     
                     ], index=ridx, columns=cidx)
dfmix
```

[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one liner :

```
dfmix['ALPHA','gamma'] = dfmix['ALPHA','alpha']
                       + dfmix.groupby(level='d1').shift()['BETA','alpha']
```

[pd.shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is the good tool to align rows like you want. the [pd.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 
is for group the rows before applying this operation.

For

```
In [6]: dfmix.sort_index(axis=1)
Out[6]: 
d3    ALPHA            BETA     
d4    alpha beta gamma alpha beta
d1 d2                            
A  1      0    1   NaN     2    3
   2     10   11    12    12   13
   3     20   21    32    22   23
B  1     30   31   NaN    32   33
   2     40   41    72    42   43
   3     50   51    92    52   53
C  1     60   61   NaN    62   63
   2     70   71   132    72   73
   3     80   81   152    82   83
```

Of course, you have Nan values if the mathematic formula has no sense.

Comment: thanks, that does what I intended. But can you please explain why there is a groupby in your formula ?

Comment: ok, I got it.. without the groupby(), shift() would have just shifted  the whole table down, while we need the shift to happen for each level 1 group of rows.. thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

You can access each unique column by `dfmix.columns[0..n]`

Following shall help to understand it better:

```
In [129]: dfmix.columns[0]
Out[129]: ('ALPHA', 'alpha')

In [134]: dfmix[dfmix.columns[0]][1]
Out[134]: 10

In [136]: dfmix.columns[2]
Out[136]: ('BETA', 'alpha')

In [137]: dfmix[dfmix.columns[2]][0]
Out[137]: 2

In [138]: dfmix[dfmix.columns[0]][1] + dfmix[dfmix.columns[2]][0]
Out[138]: 12
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer.. so I can do stuff like `dfmix[('ALPHA', 'gamma')] = dfmix[('ALPHA', 'alpha')] +  dfmix[('BETA', 'alpha')]`, but how can I do operations that involve different rows without knowing the absolute order of the row ? I did try to loop over `dfmix[('ALPHA', 'gamma')]` to get the index so that I could implement the assignment cell by cell (still I would prefer a way to do it without looping), but looping over  `dfmix[('ALPHA', 'gamma')]` returns just the cell value, not the (index,value) like I hoped...

Comment: Consider how would you select the rows if the DataFrame is not multi indexed?